# Render new Vue prop value

Tags: vue.js

I have `{{ story.score }}` in a template and a function which updates the score:

```
setup(props) {
 const changeScore = (value) => {
  props.story.score = value;
}
return {
  changeScore,
}
```

New value is assigned to `props.story.score`, but template doesn't rerender, what is missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** change props directly in vue, it wont trigger an update. The proper way is to emit changes to parent element, like this:

```js
setup({ props, emit }) {
  const changeScore = (value) => emit('update-story-score', value);

  return { changeScore }
}
```

Then just handle an event in parent, like this:

```html
<template>
  <Test :story="story" @update-story-score="updateStoryScore"></Test>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const story = reactive({ score: 1 });

    const updateStoryScore = (value) => story.score = value;

    return { story, updateStoryScore }
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue props has a [One-Way Data Flow](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#one-way-data-flow)

> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but **not the other way around**

You need to **emit an event**. Check out [v-model on components](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#v-model-with-components)